# Looping and adding features in memory layer using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis

I would like to know how to add each object obtained as an entity in the same layer; Not by creating a memory layer at  each time in this example.

```
rb = QgsRubberBand(qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas())
  rb.setColor(Qt.red)

  geom = QgsGeometry.fromPolyline(p)

for pnt in p:
    rb.addPoint(pnt)

v_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "cable", "memory")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])
pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
v_layer.startEditing()
v_layer.addAttribute(QgsField("id", QVariant.String))
v_layer.addAttribute(QgsField("type", QVariant.String))

seg = QgsFeature()
geom = rb.asGeometry()
seg.setGeometry(geom)
pr.addFeatures( [seg] )
v_layer.commitChanges()
```

Comment: What are you exactly trying to add to your memory layer (Point, Linestring??)

Comment: I am trying to add a Linestring. each linestrin added must be a feature in my memomry layer

Answer (score 2):

You just have to get your layer before adding your line feature. In your code you create a new layer each time you run your script.

Your can try the following code:

```
#create your memory layer if it doesn't exists or get it if it exists
v_layer = None
for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
   if layer.name() == 'cable':
        v_layer = layer
if v_layer is None: 
    v_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "cable", "memory")
    v_layer.addAttribute(QgsField("id", QVariant.String))
    v_layer.addAttribute(QgsField("type", QVariant.String))
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])

pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
v_layer.startEditing()


#then add your line
seg = QgsFeature()
seg.setGeometry(geom)
pr.addFeatures( [seg] )

#and save your changes
v_layer.commitChanges()
```

So if you have a layer named 'cable' load into your project the line will be add in, but i f you don't have such a layer it will be create and add to the project

Comment: Sorry i'm new in python :  what do you call   "for line in your_lines :  ........................."  what do you mean by line and your_lines? tks

Comment: how do you create your line? Where do they come from? Please Edit your question to give more information about what you are trying to do, especially give some context, it may help us to find the appropriate solution to your need.

Comment: I generate my line using a function to calculate the shortest path between 2 points.

Comment: if tree[idStop] == -1:
  print "Path not found"
else:
  p = []
  curPos = idStop
  while curPos != idStart:
    pnt = graph.vertex(graph.arc(tree[curPos]).inVertex()).point()

    p.append(pnt)
   
    curPos = graph.arc(tree[curPos]).outVertex()

  p.append(tStart)

  rb = QgsRubberBand(qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas())
  rb.setColor(Qt.red)

Comment: Ok so you want to add a new line in your layer each time you run your script. The goal is not to add several features in one time. It's more clear now so i will edit my answer.

Comment: yes i want a new line at each time i run my script but add those line in the same layer not one line one layer. thanks

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Comment: v_layer = none is refused

Comment: V_layer = None... I forgot the upper N...

Comment: It works thank you very much. but i am obliged to restart my script before adding a new line. how can i add a new line directly wihthout restarting my script. thanks

Comment: Please create a new question and give details. I'll be happy to help if you clearly explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: the new question is https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/246358/how-can-i-calculate-the-shortest-path-between-2-points-and-insert-the-line-resul